# Apache Beam Program execution without using Maven

Tags: apache-beam, apache-beam-io

I want to run a simple example Beam Program using Apache Spark runner. 
1) I was to able to compile the program in my local successfully.
2) I want to push the JAR file to QA box where Maven is not installed.
3) I see the example with Maven command which compiles and executes the examples program.
4) Could you please tell me the steps to run the code without installing Maven.
5) spark-submit command runs fine.
6) Do you want me to put all the dependent JAR files one by one in 
/opt/mapr/spark/spark-2.1.0/jars directory to execute the program

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by following the instructions in [Beam Spark Runner documentation](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/runners/spark/#deploying-spark-with-your-application).

These instructions demonstrate how to Submit your application by doing the following:

1. Packaging your application, with dependencies, as an uber jar.
2. Submit your packaged application using `spark-submit`.